# Solving Laplace's equation with fourier transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convolution, fourier-transform

I am trying to solve $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$$ where $-\infty < x <\infty$ and $0<y<1$, subject to $$u(x,0) = H(x)e^{-x}$$ $$u(x,1) = 0$$ where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function.

After applying transform in $x$, I get that the transformed solution is $U(\omega,y) = A(\omega)e^{\omega y}+B(\omega)e^{-\omega y}$, and, the boundary conditions become $$U(\omega,0) = \frac{1}{1+i\omega}$$ $$U(\omega,1) = 0$$

After applying these, I get stuck with $$B(\omega) = \frac{e^\omega}{2(1+i\omega)\sinh(\omega)}$$ and $$A(\omega) = \frac{1}{1+i\omega}\left(1-\frac{2e^{\omega}}{\sinh(\omega)}\right)$$

However, plugging this into the solution above and trying to invert this leads me nowhere. I'm not quite sure how to proceed. Any help or guidance would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After enforcing the boundary conditions, we find that

$$A(\omega)=-\frac{e^{-\omega}}{2(1+i\omega)\sinh(\omega)}$$

$$B(\omega)=\frac{e^{\omega}}{2(1+i\omega)\sinh(\omega)}$$

Then, applying the Fourier inverse transform, we obtain

$$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\omega x} \frac{\sinh(\omega(1-y))}{(1+i\omega)\sinh(\omega)}\,d\omega \tag 1$$

To evaluate the integral in $(1)$, we use contour integration.  We note that the integrand has poles at $\omega =i$ and  $\omega =in\pi$, $n\ne0$.

Enclosing the contour in the upper-half plane when $x>0$, application of the residue theorem yields

$$u(x,y)=\frac{e^{-x}\sin(1-y)}{\sin(1)}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ne^{-n\pi x}\sin(n\pi (1-y))}{n\pi -1}$$

Enclosing the contour in the lower-half plane when $x<0$, application of the residue theorem yields

$$u(x,y)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n e^{n\pi x}\sin(n\pi (1-y))}{n\pi +1}$$

Comment: It seemed to that your conversation had reached the end. So, in response to a system flag due to sheer number of comments, [I moved it to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56991/discussion-on-answer-by-dr-mv-solving-laplaces-equation-with-fourier-transform). If there were comments that you think should stay visible to all, @-ping me, or flag a diamond moderator for help.

Answer (score 1):

Separation of variables can work. Assuming boundedness of the separated solutions in the $x$ direction,
$$
                       X_{\lambda}(x)=C(\lambda)e^{i\lambda x},\;\; Y_{\lambda}(y)= A(\lambda)\sinh(\lambda y)+B(\lambda)\cosh(\lambda y).
$$
Because you want $Y_{\lambda}(0)=0$, then $Y_{\lambda}$ can be written as
$$
               Y_{\lambda}(y) = D(\lambda)\sinh(\lambda(1-y))
$$
"Summing" the separated solutions and combing constants gives an unknown coefficient function $c(\lambda)$ such that
$$
            u(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}c(\lambda)e^{i\lambda x}\sinh(\lambda(1-y))d\lambda.
$$
The coefficient function $c(\lambda)$ is determined by the condition $u(x,0)=H(x)e^{-x}$:
$$
     H(x)e^{-x}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}c(\lambda)e^{i\lambda x}\sinh(\lambda)d\lambda
$$
Applying the Fourier transform gives $c(\lambda)\sinh(\lambda)$:
$$
   \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}e^{-i\lambda x}dx =c(\lambda)\sinh(\lambda) \\
     \frac{1}{2\pi(1+i\lambda)} = c(\lambda)\sinh(\lambda)
$$
Therefore $u(x,y)$ is
$$
        u(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\lambda x}\frac{\sinh(\lambda(1-y))}{(1+i\lambda)\sinh(\lambda)}d\lambda.
$$

Comment: @Sorey : You have the full solution as an inverse Fourier transform integral. I believe what I have written is correct. Are you wanting to try to evaluate the inverse Fourier transform? Or are you want to verify that the transform integral is, indeed, the correct solution? You weren't clear about what you wanted. All you wrote was that you were trying to solve the equation. I have given you the solution, which can be verified directly.